# XSL include a non-looping element in a loop

Tags: xslt

I have an XML-file that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="gallring.xsl"?>
<report>
<title>Bibliography</title>
 <dateCreated>2016-05-17</dateCreated>
<catalog>
 <catalogKey>142343</catalogKey>
 <yearOfPublication>1936</yearOfPublication>
 <marc>
  <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Landelius, Carl</marcEntry>
  <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="00">1840-1850-talets bildningscirklar och arbetareföreningar i Sverige. 1</marcEntry>
 </marc>
 <call>
  <callNumber>374</callNumber>
  <library>VALLA</library>
  <item>
   <dateLastUsed>2009-01-06</dateLastUsed>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
 <catalogKey>661763</catalogKey>
 <yearOfPublication>1936</yearOfPublication>
 <marc>
  <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Landelius, Carl</marcEntry>
  <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="00">1840-1850-talets bildningscirklar och arbetareföreningar i Sverige / Carl Landelius</marcEntry>
 </marc>
 <call>
  <callNumber>374</callNumber>
  <library>VALLA</library>
  <item>
   <dateLastUsed>2014-06-18</dateLastUsed>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
 <catalogKey>32018</catalogKey>
 <yearOfPublication>1982</yearOfPublication>
 <marc>
  <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="00">ABF-are berättar : minnen från ABF / red.: Allan Malmgren</marcEntry>
 </marc>
 <call>
  <callNumber>374</callNumber>
  <library>VALLA</library>
  <item>
   <dateLastUsed>2008-06-17</dateLastUsed>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
```

To open it I use this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">
        <itemline>
            <callNumber><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="string(call/callNumber)"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text></callNumber>
            <yearOfPublication><xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication"/></yearOfPublication>
            <Author><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@tag='100']"/></Author>
            <Title><xsl:value-of select="substring(marc/marcEntry[@tag='245'],1,30)"/></Title>
            <dateLastUsed><xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateLastUsed"/></dateLastUsed>
        </itemline>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Problem is: I want to include the element title/dateCreated after each call/item/dateLastUsed-element so I can make calculations (in Excel) how many days has passed since dateLastUsed when the report was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to include the `dateCreated`, e.g. you can add

```
<dateCreated><xsl:value-of select="../dateCreated"/></dateCreated>
```

As you are in a `for-each` loop for every `report/catalog`, this goes one step up from the current loop and fetches the information from the current `report`.
If the "real" XML only contains one `report` like in this example, you could also write

```
<dateCreated><xsl:value-of select="//report/dateCreated"/></dateCreated>
```

to target the `dateCreated` directly from root.